# xrdp - Black Screen. Mac to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, remote-desktop, xrdp

I am using Microsoft Remote Desktop on my Mac to try to connect to Ubuntu 18.04 desktop. Using xrdp.

However, after signing in on my Mac, a black screen appears. Things I have tried:

1. Installed and upgraded graphics drivers. Nvidia.
2. allowed port 3389 using `ufw`
3. `echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession`
4. Set up colors in localauthority folders.

I am not logged into the user on the Ubuntu desktop. I don't have any more ideas left nor have I run into these troubles before.

Answer (score 0):

I just used an alternative free remote client instead: [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/).